# Php.ini Issue - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

After trying to customize a plugin I am getting this error when sending data from a post type form to a file on the server located within a plugin directory:

> `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ffmpeg.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

I'm not sure why this is happening, or how to stop it. Ideas and suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the line that has ffmpeg.so out in the php.ini with a ; before it? Save and then restart php

Comment: Don't have access to it.  It's a shared host by HostGator.com and Not sure if I can override that?

Comment: Or have you tried the following http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=30702 as there was a spelling mistake when trying to install the package

Comment: Have you got access to a control panel ie plesk c panel?

Comment: @liamsorby not sure about that.  I came in when this was already set up.

Comment: Ah what is this plugin? You should be able to go to your public_html folder in cpanel and be able to edit your copy of the php.ini from there wouldn't hurt to check

Comment: I do not see it in there.  I did a search for the php.ini file but no cigar,

Comment: Are you running php version 5.3.2?

Comment: I have seen that it is common on Wordpress in version 5.3.2 and maybe a bug however it can be commented out to rectify the error. However this maybe someone editing the php.ini file that you don't have access to so may be useful to ask your host to check this out as the library is definitely uncommented and Is unable to load

Comment: Sorry couldn't be of much help!